# how closure function access instance property

Tags: actionscript-3, function, actionscript, closures

code first

```
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class TestClosure extends Sprite
    {
        private var a:Object = {'value':'test'}

        public function TestClosure()
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,
                function (e:Event):void
                {
                    trace(a.value);//this works
//                  trace(this.a.value);this won't work
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

So as you can see, access the instance property a without "this" keyword will success.

So here's my guess, I don't know if it is correct.

When create a closure function the compiler looking for the scope variables and create a reference to it.

Using a.value, cause the compiler looking for a in function scope, and of course, var a is a  private variable it's available in the function scope.

Using this.a.value, the compiler will skip "this" because it dynamic in many circumstances, can only determined in runtime. As in closure function "this" reference to global and not he instance.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, in the closure function `this` refers to global and not local scope. But creating a reference to `this` in another variable will work:

```
public function TestClosure()
{
    var me:TestClosure = this;

    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,
         function (e:Event):void
         {
             trace(a.value);//this works
             trace(me.a.value); //this will work provided a is a public var
         }
    );
}
```

The line `trace(me.a.value);` will work as soon as you change `a` into a public variable, or make a getter function for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the function in the my post above can just access the private variable without using this or assign this to another local variable

Comment: That's right, but then I guess I don't really understand your original question, if getting a reference to the instance around the closure was not your goal. You correctly found that `this` refers to global scope in a closure. So what was the question then?

Comment: ya, you are right, that my goal and I achieve it without assigning this to another variable like you did in your code. So the question is what's the theory behind? I have my guess, but I don't if it's correct

Comment: I don't know the theory but it's pretty simple: do `trace(this)` inside a closure and it outputs something like `[global]`. So basically you can't use `this` in a closure.

Comment: That's correct, but can you explain why without using "this" keyword the closure still can get the private variable of the instance ? this is the point I am fancy about:D

Comment: That's because all functions that are defined in other functions have access to the variables defined in the function where they are defined. If you set a breakpoint in your closure, Flash Builder will show the <scope chain> with all objects and their variables that the function has access to.